# SQL Server query slow - how do optimize it?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I would like some help to optimize this query to be faster.

This query produces a view that latter will be showed in a table in a website.
This query is slow, and I am trying to make it faster.

The only thing I tried till now is to reduce the amount of columns I retrieve for the table.

This is the query:

```
SELECT        TOP (100) PERCENT Id, MAX(BusinessTitle) AS BusinessTitle, MAX(ClientName) AS ClientName, MAX(ClientType) AS Type, MAX(CreatedWhen) AS CreatedWhen, MAX(CASE WHEN C.[CreatedBy] IS NULL 
                     THEN 'Client' ELSE 'Admin' END) AS CreatedBy, CAST(MAX(CASE WHEN C.IsDisabled = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS BIT) AS IsDisabled, MAX(ReferenceSource) AS ReferenceSource, MAX(OtherReferenceSource) 
                     AS OtherReferenceSource, MAX(Address) AS Address,
                         (SELECT        MAX(T.FirstName + ' ' + T.LastName) AS Expr1
                           FROM            dbo.ApplicationUsers AS A INNER JOIN
                                                     dbo.Therapists AS T ON A.UserName = MAX(C.ClientName) AND A.Id = T.ApplicationUserId) AS ClientAdmin,
                         (SELECT        MAX(A.Email) AS Expr1
                           FROM            dbo.ApplicationUsers AS A INNER JOIN
                                                     dbo.Therapists AS T ON A.UserName = MAX(C.ClientName) AND A.Id = T.ApplicationUserId) AS Email,
                         (SELECT        MAX(Name) AS Expr1
                           FROM            dbo.Cities AS CY
                           WHERE        (Id = MAX(C.CityId))) AS City,
                         (SELECT        COUNT(*) AS Expr1
                           FROM            dbo.Patients AS P
                           WHERE        (ClientId = C.Id)) AS TotalPatientCount,
                         (SELECT        COUNT(*) AS Expr1
                           FROM            dbo.Patients AS P
                           WHERE        (ClientId = C.Id) AND (IsDeleted = 0) AND (IsDisabled = 0)) AS ActivePatientCount,
                         (SELECT        MAX(CreatedWhen) AS Expr1
                           FROM            dbo.Patients AS P
                           WHERE        (ClientId = C.Id)) AS LastPatientAddition,
                         (SELECT        COUNT(*) AS Expr1
                           FROM            dbo.Treatments AS T
                           WHERE        (ClientId = C.Id)) AS TotalTreatmentCount,
                         (SELECT        MAX(CreatedWhen) AS Expr1
                           FROM            dbo.Treatments AS T
                           WHERE        (ClientId = C.Id)) AS LastTreatmentAddition,
                         (SELECT        COUNT(*) AS Expr1
                           FROM            dbo.Therapists AS T
                           WHERE        (ClientId = C.Id)) AS TotalTherapistCount,
                         (SELECT        COUNT(*) AS Expr1
                           FROM            dbo.Therapists AS T INNER JOIN
                                                     dbo.ApplicationUsers AS A ON T.ClientId = C.Id AND T.ApplicationUserId = A.Id
                           WHERE        (A.IsDeleted = 0) AND (A.IsDisabled = 0)) AS ActiveTherapistCount,
                         (SELECT        MAX(A.CreatedWhen) AS Expr1
                           FROM            dbo.Therapists AS T INNER JOIN
                                                     dbo.ApplicationUsers AS A ON T.ClientId = C.Id AND T.ApplicationUserId = A.Id) AS LastTherapistAddition,
                         (SELECT        MAX(A.LastLoginDate) AS Expr1
                           FROM            dbo.Therapists AS T INNER JOIN
                                                     dbo.ApplicationUsers AS A ON T.ClientId = C.Id AND T.ApplicationUserId = A.Id
                           WHERE        (A.LastLoginDate IS NOT NULL)) AS TherapistLastLoginDate, CAST((CASE WHEN
                         ((SELECT        COUNT(S.[Id])
                             FROM            [dbo].[ClientSubscriptions] AS S
                             WHERE        ((S.[ClientId] = C.[Id]) AND (S.[IsDeleted] = 0) AND ((S.[SubscriptionEnd] IS NULL) OR
                                                      (S.[SubscriptionEnd] > GETDATE())))) > 0) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS BIT) AS HasActiveSubscription,
                         (SELECT        MAX(SubscriptionEnd) AS Expr1
                           FROM            dbo.ClientSubscriptions AS S
                           WHERE        (ClientId = C.Id) AND (IsDeleted = 0) AND (SubscriptionEnd IS NULL OR
                                                     SubscriptionEnd > GETDATE())) AS LastValidSubscriptionEnd, CAST((CASE WHEN
                         ((SELECT        COUNT(S.[Id])
                             FROM            [dbo].[ClientSubscriptions] AS S
                             WHERE        ((S.[ClientId] = C.[Id]) AND (S.[IsDeleted] = 0) AND ((S.[SubscriptionEnd] IS NULL) OR
                                                      (S.[SubscriptionEnd] > GETDATE())) AND (S.[Id] <>
                                                          (SELECT        MIN(S2.[Id])
                                                            FROM            [dbo].[ClientSubscriptions] AS S2
                                                            WHERE        ((S2.[ClientId] = C.[Id]) AND (S2.[IsDeleted] = 0)))))) > 0) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS BIT) AS IsPayingCustomer, COALESCE
                         ((SELECT        MAX(MonthlyPrice) AS Expr1
                             FROM            dbo.ClientSubscriptions AS S
                             WHERE        (ClientId = C.Id) AND (IsDeleted = 0) AND (SubscriptionEnd IS NULL OR
                                                      SubscriptionEnd > GETDATE()) AND (MonthlyPrice > 0)), 0.00) AS ActiveSubscriptionMonthlyPrice, MAX(ClientStatus) AS Status, MAX(Phone1) AS Phone, MAX(Phone2) AS Phone2,
                         (SELECT        Code
                           FROM            dbo.DiscountCoupons AS DC
                           WHERE        (Code =
                                                         (SELECT        TOP (1) DiscountCouponCode
                                                           FROM            dbo.ClientPayments AS CP
                                                           WHERE        (ClientId = C.Id)
                                                           ORDER BY Id))) AS DiscountCouponCode,
                         (SELECT        IssuedTo
                           FROM            dbo.DiscountCoupons AS DC
                           WHERE        (Code =
                                                         (SELECT        TOP (1) DiscountCouponCode
                                                           FROM            dbo.ClientPayments AS CP
                                                           WHERE        (ClientId = C.Id)
                                                           ORDER BY Id))) AS DiscountCouponIssuedTo,
                         (SELECT        ClientDiscount
                           FROM            dbo.DiscountCoupons AS DC
                           WHERE        (Code =
                                                         (SELECT        TOP (1) DiscountCouponCode
                                                           FROM            dbo.ClientPayments AS CP
                                                           WHERE        (ClientId = C.Id)
                                                           ORDER BY Id))) AS DiscountCouponClientDiscount, COALESCE
                         ((SELECT        COUNT(Id) AS Expr1
                             FROM            dbo.ClientFiles AS F
                             WHERE        (ClientId = C.Id)), 0) AS TotalFilesCount, COALESCE
                         ((SELECT        SUM(FileSize) AS Expr1
                             FROM            dbo.ClientFiles AS F
                             WHERE        (ClientId = C.Id)), 0) / 1048576.0 AS TotalFilesSize, CAST(MAX(CASE WHEN C.CrmEnded = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS BIT) AS CrmEnded, MAX(CrmStatus) AS CrmStatus, MAX(CrmUnuseReason) 
                     AS CrmUnuseReason,
                         (SELECT        COUNT(1) AS Expr1
                           FROM            dbo.Tipulog_Crm_Calls_new AS CC
                           WHERE        (Cust_id = C.Id)) AS CrmCallCount
FROM            dbo.Clients AS C
WHERE        (IsDeleted = 0)
GROUP BY Id
```

Comment: How do you expect us to read your query and understand what you are trying to do with out any explaination at all ? Please format your query and provide some explanation with sample data and expected result

Comment: i am sorry i am new to stackoverflow so i didn't know how to make my code be in a good manaer. fixing it now thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: thank you for the link. is it understandable now?

Comment: You need to post an execution plan if you want help with performance.

Comment: how to add the execution plan  like an image?

Comment: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: There is no way I have ever seen a query that requires so many nested subqueries. For a start there are many that reference the same tables - add a subquery that does all this in one place and join to it. You have got to resolve some of these out if you want decent performance.

Comment: thank you TomC, i will try it. can you show me an example?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read the [T-SQL tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tsql/info) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: thank you i wiil edit my question, and delete the t-sql tag

Comment: Get rid of "top (100) percent" - that does nothing useful. Are you creating a view? If so, forget you ever heard or tried to create a "sorted view". A view, like a table, has no defined order. If you want a resultset from this view that has rows in a particular order, then the query that generates the resultset must include an order by clause.

Comment: Does the table dbo.Clients contain multiple rows for a given ID value? My guess is "no". If not, then you also don't need to group by that column nor do you need aggregates for the other columns of that table.

Comment: @Ben.S . . . You should ask a *new* question with sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you want and see what kind of queries you get.  They will -- no doubt -- look quite different from your current query.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answers SMor and Gordon Linoff. I will try your suggestions SMor and also will try to add sample data and the desired results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will add a second answer, which is the complete sql. This has of course not been tested as we have no access to your data, but I think you should be able to debug it yourself. There are many pointers in this code that should show you how to go.

The basic thing is to take out all of the correlated queries and put them as subqueries. The only reason to do this is all the Max/Min you use - I would look at those as if they are not necessary depending on your data then you should take them out and join to the tables directly. All the subqueries are left joins - again make them normal joins if you can depending on your data.

Also took out the outside group by Id, as 99% sure this is not necessary, as is the Top 100% bit.

```
SELECT  BusinessTitle, ClientName, ClientType AS Type, CreatedWhen, 
        CASE WHEN C.[CreatedBy] IS NULL THEN 'Client' ELSE 'Admin' END) AS CreatedBy, 
        CAST(CASE WHEN C.IsDisabled = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BIT) AS IsDisabled, 
        ReferenceSource, OtherReferenceSource, Address,
        ApplicationByName.FullName AS ClientAdmin,
        ApplicationByName.Email AS Email,
        Cities.Name AS City,
        Patients.TotalPatientCount,
        Patients.ActivePatientCount,
        Patients.LastPatientAddition,
        Treatments.TotalTreatmentCount,
        Treatments.LastTreatmentAddition,
        Therapists.TotalTherapistCount,
        Therapists.ActiveTherapistCount,
        Therapists.LastTherapistAddition,
        Therapists.TherapistLastLoginDate
        CAST(CASE WHEN Subscriptions.SubscriptionCount>0 then 1 else 0 end as BIT) as HasActiveSubscription,
        Subscriptions.LastValidSubscriptionEnd
        CAST(Subscriptions.IsPayingCustomer AS BIT) AS IsPayingCustomer, 
        COALESCE(ActiveSubscriptionMonthlyPrice,0) as ActiveSubscriptionMonthlyPrice
        ClientStatus AS Status, Phone1 AS Phone, Phone2 AS Phone2,
        ClientPayments.DiscountCouponCode,
        DiscountCoupons.IssuedTo AS DiscountCouponIssuedTo,
        DiscountCoupons.ClientDiscount AS DiscountCouponClientDiscount, 
        COALESCE(ClientFiles.TotalFilesCount,0) AS TotalFilesCount, 
        COALESCE(ClientFiles.TotalFilesSize,0) AS TotalFilesSize, 
        CAST((CASE WHEN C.CrmEnded = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS BIT) AS CrmEnded, 
        CrmStatus, CrmUnuseReason,
        Crm_Calls.CrmCallCount
FROM dbo.Clients AS C
left join (
    select A.UserName,
        max(T.FirstName + ' ' + T.LastName) as FullName,
        max(A.Email) as Email
    from dbo.ApplicationUsers A
    join dbo.Therapists T on T.ApplicationUserId=A.Id
    group by A.Username
    ) ApplicationByName on ApplicationByName.UserName=C.ClientName
join dbo.Cities on Cities.ID=c.CityID
left join (
    SELECT ClientId,
        COUNT(*) AS TotalPatientCount,
        sum(case when IsDeleted = 0 AND IsDisabled = 0 then 1 else 0 end) AS ActivePatientCount,
        MAX(CreatedWhen) AS LastPatientAddition
    FROM  dbo.Patients
    GROUP BY ClientId
    ) Patients on Patients.ClientId = C.Id
left join (
    SELECT ClientId,
        COUNT(*) AS TotalTreatmentCount,
        MAX(CreatedWhen) AS LastTreatmentAddition
    FROM dbo.Treatments
    GROUP BY ClientId
    ) Treatments on Treatments.ClientID = C.Id
left join (
    select T.ClientId, 
        count(distinct T.Id) as TotalTherapistCount,
        sum(case when A.IsDeleted = 0 AND A.IsDisabled = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as ActiveTherapistCount,
        max(A.CreatedWhen) as LastTherapistAddition,
        max(A.LastLoginDate) as TherapistLastLoginDate
    from Therapists T
    left join dbo.ApplicationUsers A on A.Id=T.ApplicationUserId 
    group by T.ClientId
    ) Therapists on Therapists.ClientID = C.Id
left join (
    SELECT S.ClientId,
        count(*) as SubscriptionCount,
        MAX(SubscriptionEnd) as LastValidSubscriptionEnd,
        MAX(case when MinSub.Id!=S.ID then 1 else 0 end as IsPayingCustomer,
        max(case when MonthlyPrice>0 then 0 end) as ActiveSubscriptionMonthlyPrice
    FROM dbo.ClientSubscriptions S
    join (
        select ClientId, min(Id) as Id 
        from dbo.ClientSubscriptions 
        where IsDeleted=0 
        group by ClientId
        ) MinSub on MinSub.ClientId=ClientSubscriptions.ClientId
    where IsDeleted=0 and (SubscriptionEnd is null or SubscriptionEnd>getdate())
    group by ClientId
    ) Subscriptions on Subscriptions.ClientId=C.Id
left join (
    select ClientId, 
        DiscountCouponCode,
        row_number() over(partition by ClientId, order by Id) rn
    from  dbo.ClientPayments
    ) ClientPayments on ClientPayments.ClientId=C.ID and rn=1
left join dbo.DiscountCoupons on DiscountCoupons.Code=ClientPayments.DiscountCouponCode
left join (
    select ClientId,
        count(*) as TotalFilesCount,
        sum(FileSize)/1048576.0 as TotalFilesSize
    from dbo.ClientFiles
    group by ClientId
    ) ClientFiles on ClientFiles.ClientId=Client.Id
left join (
    SELECT Cust_id, COUNT(1) AS CrmCallCount
    FROM dbo.Tipulog_Crm_Calls_new 
    group by Cust_id
    ) Crm_Calls on Crm_Calls.Cust_id=C.Id
WHERE C.IsDeleted = 0
```

Comment: thanks for all your help. by the way this is not my sql query, i was asked to improve it , I will try your changes thank a lot.

Comment: Hi TomC, your query was great, it improved the query by 4 sec' thanks a lot!

Comment: Great @Ben.S Remember to accept the answer if you are happy with it.

Comment: Hi @TomC do you think that there is another way to optimize this query? its faster but can it be more?

Comment: I assume all the relevant indexes are in place? Also, some other threads find that replacing the left join with CROSS APPLY might be quicker so you could try that. Without having your data its hard to say.

Comment: I am adding the actual execution plan  I hope it will help 
 https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BypAm97Jr

Answer (score 1):

This is a very partial answer, but you asked how to refer to a table once instead of multiple times in multiple subqueries.

This is an example of how you would replace all those subqueries to the Patients & Treatments tables, and also the cities table. You really need to learn about joins.

```
FROM dbo.Clients AS C
join dbo.Cities on Cities.ID=c.CityID
left join (
    SELECT ClientId,
        COUNT(*) AS TotalPatientCount,
        sum(case when IsDeleted = 0 AND IsDisabled = 0 then 1 else 0 end) AS ActivePatientCount,
        MAX(CreatedWhen) AS LastPatientAddition
    FROM  dbo.Patients
    GROUP BY ClientId
    ) Patients on Patients.ClientId = C.Id
left join (
    SELECT ClientId,
        COUNT(*) AS TotalTreatmentCount,
        MAX(CreatedWhen) AS LastTreatmentAddition
    FROM dbo.Treatments
    GROUP BY ClientId
    ) Treatments on Treatments.ClientID = C.Id
```

Then your column list replaces the subqueries to Patients and City like this:

```
Cities.Name AS City,
Patients.TotalPatientCount,
Patients.ActivePatientCount,
Patients.LastPatientAddition,
Treatments.TotalTreatmentCount,
Treatments.LastTreatmentAddition,
```

That should at least give you an idea.

Comment: thank you TomC I will try to follow your example  to reduce these subqueries

Comment: i tride your changes TomC but i got less result from what it should be.  i erased all the subqueries that uses the Cities and Patients tables, and also add that join and columns list but got less results. can you give an example on how to combain the subqueries them self?  i mean like the first subquery and the second subquery. I am using a DB that have a weak table and reference tuning.

Comment: @Ben.S I have added a second subquery, and also changequery.d the joins to left joins as I guess some clients may have no patients, which may be why you had less rows. Even if you do this for some of your subqueries it should improve your performance. Also of course make sure you have INDEXES on ClientID in your Patients, Treatments, etc tables.

Comment: And by the way - you could also do my joined queries as CTEs if you prefer that syntax. It should be identical result but you might find it easier to read.

Comment: thank you very much. you are currect about that left join! the results are now the same as it should be. i  read about CTEs i will try to use them also. i will appreciate if you can give an example to CTEs.

Comment: and another thing TomC do tou see those "SubscriptionEnd" querys. if you can help me unite them to be one or somthing else that they will be faster thanks!